# Render Blender outside of blender GUI with Python

Tags: python, blender, bpy

So I have a flask setup that allows users to make mock-ups, they post their image, it gets cropped so all the images have the same dimensions, either it is a landscape image, a square image or a portrait image. Next up, I want the blender file to render, but if it's portrait image, the portrait.blend renders ect. How can I run a render with bpy outside of blender?

Comment: Welcome to SO, What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) wherever required. Also please take the time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: I don't understand the question. You can run blender in background mode and pass script to execute, I suppose that should be enough.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) to run blender from your flask code, by giving it the [`--background` argument](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/command_line/arguments.html) it will not start a gui, you can also use the `--python` argument to specify a script to run.

```
import subprocess as sp
sp.call(['blender','--background','portrait.blend','--python','myscript.py'])
```